# Use of CONCAT in FROM clause

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a non-working query as the sub-query `FROM` clause doesn't understand `CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `events` e
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
              FROM CONCAT('prefix_', e.`event_id`) registrations
              WHERE registrations.`attendee` = 123456
             )
```

Is there any way to make this work in a single-statement?

The error message I receive is:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('prefix_', e.event_id) registrations

Comment: Just to make sure I'm reading this right... you have loads of tables named prefix_1, prefix_2, and want to select and join them dynamically in your query?

Comment: @Erik : yes, I have hundreds of tables "prefix_something" and I'd like to select all the events where Attendee 123456 is registered.

Comment: I don't think that's possible and it is most definately not how SQL is supposed to be used. Why are you doing it like this?

Comment: @Erik : so it's not possible in MySQL. I saw that it's possible with MS Access to create table names dynamically.

Comment: The easiest way to fix this would be to normalise your database design. Have a single event registration table with the event_id as a column rather then part of the table name.

Comment: @AeroX : actually it wouldn't change the actual issue, which is dynamically-build table names... but with Priyank's approach, I'm getting closer

Comment: @Frank1999 I'm saying the best way to fix this is to completely get rid to the dynamically built table names and instead have one table with a column to denote which event the row is for. With proper indexing this would be a far better way to save and retrieve the data

Comment: You seem to be making things needlessly complicated. What is your reason for settings things up like this?

Comment: First, a portion of the code/data must not be modified (new module over existing one) and second I wanted to have a single-statement query to avoid a second loop in my PHP page. It works with 2 queries and 2 loops, but it isn't very elegant in my opinion. If you have any suggestion to improve things, please feel free to tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to dynamically come up with a table name?  I don't think this is possible...because doesn't the FROM clause table name need to be resolved prior to the SQL being able to be evaluated and executed?

Comment: More explanation found here (prepare/execute) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379088/mysql-create-table-dynamically

Comment: Short answer : it's not possible in a single-statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, 
          CONCAT('prefix_', `event_id`) as prefix FROM  `events`  
          WHERE events.attendee = 123456
         );
```

Comment: #1146 - Table 'registrations' doesn't exist

Comment: Okay, now we're getting somewhere : your reverted approach seems to be getting promising results. There are some mistakes in your proposed code I had to correct. I'll come up with a clean solution in a few moments.

Comment: @Frank1999 for exact result you need to show your schema.then only i'll solve.and upvote if satisfied with answer

Comment: @Priyank As the query is currently written there is no need for the outer part of the sub-query. You could just run the inner query on it's own

Comment: @Priyank : unfortunately, I'm still stuck with dynamically built table names error, even with your interesting proposition.