# MySQL: Is it possible to store type in a variable and use it in expression

Tags: mysql, variables, types, expression

In MySQL, is it possible to store a type in a variable and use it in following expressions ? The reason is to reduce code duplicity and avoid possible problems when editing existing scripts when it is mandatory to use the same type. For example:

```
SET @type_ := varchar(42);
CREATE TABLE my_table1 (id @type_);
CREATE TABLE my_table2 (id @type_);
CREATE TABLE my_table3 (id @type_);
```

Comment: Using dynamic SQL yes.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379088/mysql-create-table-dynamically  but straight SQL syntax no.

Comment: Genius ! Should have thought of that. Thanks !