# how to create database with subquery's return value name?

Tags: mysql

I want to create database using subquery's return value name

```
CREATE DATABASE (SELECT (REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( standard_name, ' ', '' ), '-', '' ), '_', '' )) FROM standard_master WHERE _id = 1)
```

My Subquery return value

> SELECT (REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( standard_name, ' ', '' ), '-', ''
>   ), '_', '' )) FROM standard_master WHERE _id = 1

**standard01**

Create database query give me an syntax error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '(SELECT (REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( standard_name, ' ', '' ),
>   '-', '' ), '_', ''' at line 1

Comment: What is your question about, do you really mean database and if so what isn't working?

Comment: what does your query say when you execute it?

Comment: Question edited. now you understand my question @JoakimDanielson

Comment: You cannot do this using a subquery (the database name has to be a string literal), you need to use [dynamic sql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14379088/6248528) for this.

Comment: Why Negative vote? If you didnt understand anything in question then tell me what can i do for you. Is My quetion worng?

Comment: You need to build a string containing your sql code and execute it, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999200/is-it-possible-to-execute-a-string-in-mysql

Comment: Thank you @JoakimDanielson for your time. it's resolved by below solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are trying to create a database by fetching database name from a query. You can use a variable as :

- declare a variable and store the output of your query
- use variable in dynamic sql to create a database.

example:

```
SELECT @id := (REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( standard_name, ' ', '' ), '-', '' ), '_', '' )) FROM standard_master WHERE _id = 1;
# database name is in the @id variable
SET @SQL = CONCAT('CREATE DATABASE ', @id);
PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
# execute the statement that you have created
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

credit: I have used https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14397/creating-a-table-from-variable-names as reference for dynamic sql.

Hope it answers your query.