# Pass database name as a parameter in mySQL

Tags: mysql, database, clone

```
 set @sourcedb = 'testdb1'   set @destinationdb = 'testdb2'  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS @destinationdb.Testtable Like @sourcedb.Testtable;
```

I have tried copy one table  from one database to another database with same name.
how to pass database name as a parameter?

Comment: That would require dynamic SQL.

Comment: Could you please share example for the same(for above query)?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried that before but id doesn't work. I wonder if there's a way to that way though. In the meantime I'm just using prepared statement instead. See example query below:

```
SET @ctable='CREATE TABLE testdb12.testtable LIKE testdb21.testtable'; 
PREPARE stmt FROM @ctable;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Now, I don't really know your usage but in my case, I use this to create a new table on the 1st every month. So I keep this query in a text file, use a batch script to call it and then use task schedule to execute it every 1st of the month (yes, I'm using Windows). Hopefully, this might be what you're looking for.

*I found this solution in one of the answer here but I can't remember/didn't bookmark the solution. I would like to credit this properly.

Edit : I found this [mysql create table dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379088/mysql-create-table-dynamically) .. maybe you can use it