# Dynamically Build a sql table from another tables rows

Tags: mysql

I want to create a table from another tables data. For example this is table 1:-

| field_name | field_type | ticket_id(table name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| order_id | int | 1 |
| name | varchar | 1 |

And the new table should look like that:-

| order_id | name |
| --- | --- |

And of course they should be in the same type that declared in the first table.

Comment: Please convert your images to [tables](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables)

Comment: Use empty lines before (and after) the table on stackoverflow, or else the output goes wrong ....

Comment: I think now its ok

Comment: Where/How is the name defined for the new table ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysql create table dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379088/mysql-create-table-dynamically)

Comment: actually there is another column in the table 1 which be the table name

Comment: unfortunately not.

Comment: because i want to create the new table based on the rows of the table1

Comment: This looks like pivot using conditional aggregation but it’s not clear how many rows per ticket in source

Comment: its dynamic, so for example for ticket id = 1 all the rows become the column of the new table

Comment: add Output of show create table table1 please. I assume fieldtype is something you wish to impose rather than actual definition